# How to tune mySQL 8.0 database?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

My MySQL database was initially performing well, but as the application has grown, I'm facing significant performance issues. Queries are running slow, and there's an overall decrease in the speed of operations. I'm looking for effective ways to optimize my database. Any suggestions on the best approach to tune my MySQL database?

Here are the details of my environment to give you a clearer picture:

Server Configuration: The application and MySQL are running on the same server.

Application Details: I am running a WordPress site, served using Nginx and PHP-FPM.

MySQL Version: The MySQL version in use is 8.0.

Dataset and Buffer Pool: I am not entirely sure if my dataset fits in the buffer pool. I would appreciate guidance on how to determine this and optimize the innodb_buffer_pool_size accordingly.

Slow Query Log: The slow query log has not been analyzed yet. I am seeking advice on the best practices for enabling and analyzing the slow query log in MySQL.

Performance Schema: I have not enabled the Performance Schema. Any suggestions on how to use this effectively for performance tuning would be very helpful.

Given these specifics, I am looking for targeted advice on optimizing MySQL performance under these conditions. Any suggestions or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous post [How to tune mySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77653912/205233) that got closed because you didn't respond to comments asking for clarification. This context is lost here and the same clarifications will be asked here again. Please read [ask].

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Slowlog:  See my blog  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog